# Combinatorics: Sampling with Replacement (Door Key Question)

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

You have a key ring with N keys, exactly one of which is your house key. You randomly try one key at a time until you get the correct key. However, you mix the keys that you have already tried with ones that you have not tried.

i) Use counting techniques to determine the probability that you get the correct key for the first time on the $n^{th}$ try ($n \in N$).

For this one, I know that I should treat this as sampling *with* replacement, but do not how to proceed.

ii) Determine the probability that you get the correct key on or before the $n^{th}$ try by using (1) a direct counting and (2) the result from part (i) and the additivity property of a probability measure.

Here, it seems as though the complementation rule would be helpful, but do not know how to begin it.

Answer (score 0):

(1) This is a "word" or "balls in bins" problem. So we have $k-1$ wrong keys, and we need those to appear $n-1$ consecutive times. Then our desired key appears last. This gives us: $(k-1)^{n-1}$ as our numerator. We have enumerated all the valid possibilities.

There are $k^{n}$ ways to enumerate $k$ keys. So we divide out: $(k-1)^{n-1}/k^{n}$.

(2.1) Complementation sounds good to me. So our total probability is $1$. We subtract out the odds of not getting our desired key in the first $n$ tries. So we have $(k-1)$ keys and this is a "word" problem again: $(k-1)^{n}/k^{n}$. So our probability is $1 - (k-1)^{n}/k^{n}$.

(2.2) Using the key the first time with $n$ possible keys are disjoint for each such $n$. So we add up based on the result for (1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(k-1)^{i}}{k^{i}} $$